# Facebookの承認画面でOKを押すと画面が真っ白になり何も起こらない

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

現在Facebookに記事等を投稿する機能を作っており、ボタンを押すとFacebookにログインさせるために以下のコードを実行しています。

```
        if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil) {

        } else {
            let login:FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            login.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self.viewController, handler: { (result:FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    print("error!")
                    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
                } else if result.isCancelled {
                    print("cancelled!")
                    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
                } else {
                    print("success!")
                }
            })
        }
```

上記のようにFacebookのログイン機能を実装しているのですが、ログイン（承認？）の画面が表示された時に画面右下のOKボタンを押すと、その後別のページに飛んだかと思うと、真っ白のページのままでそれ以降全く何も表示されません。
しかもエラー等のハンドリングが何もないのでどうすればいいのか全くわかりません。
なぜ画面が真っ白なままなのでしょうか？ログインはできているのでしょうか？
どなたかわかる方がいればこの解決方法を教えていただきたいです。
宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

AppDelegate.swiftを以下のようにするといいですよ。

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

省略
```